# Saving a .m file generates internal error

Tags: front-end, kernel

Why does saving a .m file in version 10 generate this error? Nothing appears when I click on the link. But it happens everytime I save a file and then the file is renamed to untitled-n file.

> INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: FileNotify|c|305
>       Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research.

model1 =
  {
 m1->
 {
   {
    {ul'[t]==k1p*s*(100-ul[t])/(km1+(100-ul[t]))-k2p*ul[t]/(km2+ul[t])-k5p*ul[t]*um[t]/(km5+ul[t])},

    {um'[t]==k3p*uc[t]*(100-um[t])/(km3+(100-um[t]))-k4p*um[t]/(km4+um[t])},
    {uc'[t]==k6p*ul[t]*(100-uc[t])/(km6+(100-uc[t]))-k7p*uc[t]/(km7+uc[t])}
   },
    {ul[0]==0.,um[0]==0.,uc[0]==0.0},
    {k1p, km1, k2p, km2, k5p, km5, k3p, km3, k4p, km4, k6p, km6, k7p, km7},
    {ul,um,uc}
 }
};
 #&/@{model1}>>"~/Documents/models.m"
 test=<<"~/Documents/models.m";

Comment: Do you mind sharing a `Minimal Code Example` with the community, reproducing `the one error`?

Comment: @Lou, Sure the code above is an example that I just want to save... using standard methods, File->Save sort of things...

Comment: I don't know how to respond to m_goldberg...

Comment: Try to set your Dir with `SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]` and check your export Coding.

Comment: Setting the Directory works and saving works for the first iteration... However the I discovered that the problem occurs on the subsequent saves. I've sent a note to wolfram to further investigate. Thanks for the reply @Lou

Comment: My pleasure, please keep the community up to date and let us know the answer from WRI.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following.

```
Directory[]
```

Next run the following

```
NotebookSave[Notebook[{}], FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "savetest.m"}]]
```

If you receive an error I would try reinstalling Mathematica.